# C# class ctor that receives a cpp/cli object results in error 'not supported by the language'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, clr

My solution has two projects: a C# exe and a cpp clr dll.
Class1 and Class2 are cpp/clr classes implemented in the dll, and Class1's constructor expects a Class2 object: `Class1(Class2 cl2)`
When I try to instantiate it in my C# class I get the following error:

```
Error CS0570 'Class1.Class1(?)' is not supported by the language.
```

What should I do?
My code below:

```
// cpp_dll.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace cpp_dll {

    public ref class Class2
    {

    };

    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        Class1(Class2 cl2);
    };
}
------------------
// cpp_dll.cpp.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "cpp_dll.h"

cpp_dll::Class1::Class1(Class2 cl2)
{

}
-------------------
//MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.Windows;
using cpp_dll;

namespace csharp_app
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 cl1 = new Class1(new Class2()); //here I get CS0570
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the constructor of Class1 like this:

```
public:
  Class1(Class2^ cl2); <--use ^
```

In c# project you pass a pointer of a Class2 object, so you should accept a pointer of Class2 object in Class1 constructor.

Comment: Thanks.  It should be a ref, but the solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I missed it out of arrogance:

Class2 is a ref class, so it should be passed as so (see below):

### Class1(Class2 ^ cl2); // in the .h

### cpp_dll::Class1::Class1(Class2 ^ cl2) //in the cpp

var cl2 = new Class2(); //in the .cs

### Class1 cl1 = new Class1(cl2); //ref should get writable object

no bonus this month )-: